# How to create 3d ribbon box in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the 3d ribbon box in **CSS3** but getting some problems so how can i make this with pure **CSS** with minimum code.

Here is the image what i am trying to making.....

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, pretty minimal markup.  `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements  require IE 8+, if you need to support lower (IE6/7) you could use two extra `<div>` elements for the triangle corners.

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsvyk/)

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="ribbon">3d Text and rounded corner sample</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    position:relative;
    background:gray;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    margin:20px 45px;
}
#ribbon {
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:-20px;
    width:360px;
    height:55px;
    background:#ff2702;
    color:white;
    padding:20px 40px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    box-shadow:0 0 8px #333;
    text-shadow:0 0 8px #000;
}
#ribbon:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-20px;
    left:0;
    border-top:solid 10px #ff2702;
    border-right:solid 10px #ff2702;
    border-bottom:solid 10px transparent;
    border-left:solid 10px transparent;
}
#ribbon:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-20px;
    right:0;
    border-top:solid 10px #ff2702;
    border-right:solid 10px transparent;
    border-bottom:solid 10px transparent;
    border-left:solid 10px #ff2702;
}
​
```

Comment: hey @mdmullix your anwser was right but you defined all four border properties thats why there were some difference in your arrow border check it my how did i make http://jsfiddle.net/EKs3a/30/ and compare it with your answer you will get idea what i am talking about anyways thanks for your answer....

Comment: Hi, mdmullinax, how can I make the corners rounded instead of flat one? can you re-code that fiddle for the rounded corners please. Thanks

Comment: @soflover try `#box { border-radius:5px }`

Comment: I am not talking about the corner of the #box. I want the "triangular" shape of the style to be "curved". I tried to use "semi-circle" style of the CSS properties, and somehow looks good but it looks poor UI. Any idea about that please?

Comment: adjusting the `border-radius` on the `#ribbon` to be `5px` all around and adjusting the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, you can basically get that effect http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/fsvyk/10/