# CSS ribbon with inside arrow on the right

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to create a ribbon effect like on this image (the red part of image):
[image: ribbon example]

When I try to create an arrow effect with borders, the shape of object is completely destroyed:

HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="mali_oglas_kategorija">Kategorija</a>
```

CSS code so far (without trying to create the arrow):

```
.mali_oglas_kategorija {        
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block; 
    font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;        
    padding: 6px 20px 6px 40px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px -18px;
        color: #e5e5e5 !important;
    background-color: #760000;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);}    
.mali_oglas_kategorija:after{
        content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    border-width: 5px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #470000 #470000 transparent transparent;
}
```

Any idea how can I create this?

Comment: Well from which page is this? You could look up the HTML and stylesheet code (if it's not an image) and write something similar.

Comment: This is image send to me by designer (he doesn't know to code) and I need somehow to create this :D

Comment: @Sasha please check it this one:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409248/how-to-create-3d-ribbon-box-in-css

Comment: Well, this is the way to do it, but shadow doesn't follow the shape of an arrow. I guess I will need to use image.

Comment: You can give z-index:-1 to the pseudo elements  http://jsfiddle.net/fsvyk/8/

Answer (score 3):

[Made a fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6uyfq/) Couldn't solve it without a b tag though. I used b because it is so small

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="mali_oglas_kategorija">Kategorija<b></b></a>
```

CSS

```css
.mali_oglas_kategorija {        
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;        
    padding: 6px 20px 6px 40px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px -18px;
    color: #e5e5e5 !important;
    background-color: #760000;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);}    
.mali_oglas_kategorija:before{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    border-width: 5px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #470000 #470000 transparent transparent;
}

.mali_oglas_kategorija:after{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -10px;
    top: 0;
    border-width: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #760000 transparent transparent #760000  ;
}
.mali_oglas_kategorija b {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-width: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:  transparent transparent #760000 #760000 ;
}


body { padding: 50px;}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a skewed element if this was required for hit-testing as well.

Something like:

```css
.rib {
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.rib:before,
.rib:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  background: inherit;
}
.rib:before {
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
.rib:after {
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  top: 50%;
}
.shad {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  background: dimgray;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="rib">123
  <div class="shad">
  </div>
</div>
```